# How to set text when using app cards inside TWTRComposerViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, twitter

Is there a way to set custom tweet text when using Twitter SDK and `TWTRComposerViewController` to tweet app cards from inside of an app? `TWTRComposerViewController` doesn't have the properties needed for such customization, neither does `TWTRCardConfiguration`, which is embedded inside it. Is there a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround I found to do the job was subclassing TWTRComposerViewController and interating through its internals to find the appropriate text container and set the text there.

Interface:

```
@interface CMTWTRConposerViewControlller : TWTRComposerViewController

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, copy) NSString *tweetText;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation CMTWTRConposerViewControlller

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([subview respondsToSelector:@selector(textView)]) {
            UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)[subview performSelector:@selector(textView)];
            if ([textView isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
                textView.text = self.tweetText;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is swift version with latest TwitterKit

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    for sub1 in self.view.subviews {
        for sub2 in sub1.subviews {
            for sub3 in sub2.subviews {
                if let textView = sub3 as? UITextView {
                    textView.text = "test"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```